# What is the code that &x outputs to console?

Tags: c++, c++11

If i do this

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
int g;
int h;

cout << &a << endl;
cout << &b << endl;
cout << &c << endl;
cout << &d << endl;
cout << &e << endl;
cout << &f << endl;
cout << &g << endl;
cout << &h << endl;
```

and in console I get this:
0020F96C
0020F960
0020F954
0020F948
0020F93C
0020F930
0020F924
0020F918

Comment: It's the address of `x`.

Comment: See description for `'address of'`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: Note that in your case you are outputting the address of an unintialised variable

Comment: @EdChum It does not matter, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the location in memory where the `x` is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Its an address of 'x'.
here you are printing the address of x.

Answer (score 0):

You opted to print the address of x, and that's what is printed when you have:

```
cout << &x ;
```